# JSP - no JSTL tags are called after response.sendRedirect, but JSP expressions are called

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, jstl, setattribute

servlet code:

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

 session.setAttribute("mapCarBean", mapCarBean);
 session.setAttribute("testing", mapCarBean.size());

 response.sendRedirect("/sasha/jsp/main.jsp");
```

jsp code:

```
 <% System.out.println("was here"); %>

 ${sessionScope.testing}

 <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.mapCarBean}">
          found
     </c:when>

     <c:otherwise>
         not found
     </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>

 <c:forEach items="${mapCarBean}" var="entry">
     <ul>
         <li>${entry.value.getName()}</li>
     </ul>
 </c:forEach>
```

"was here" is printed after redirecting to the jsp, but none of the jstl tags are executed, until the page is manually refreshed. Even the choose isn't called

Note: I've tried sessionScope.mapCarBean and it has the same problem

SOLUTION FOUND:

After pulling my hair out I finally found the problem. I was using an AJAX post, which will not redirect. For some reason it would execute the JSP tags, but nothing else. I'm not sure why this is but hope this is helpful to anyone else reading this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove if you have this line in your jsp ,

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

it removes session from the page

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yah, I don't have it on any pages and even setting it ="true" doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt work ? Are you not getting the result till manual refresh

Comment: And from your comment , no need to use `value` in that. just try iterating the list as `${entry}` inside `forEach` loop

Comment: I think the issue might be with request.sendRedirect because if i try to request.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com"); it doesn't do anything. Setting sendRedirect to my current page executes JSP code but the page never refreshes. Also, I couldn't, for the life of me, get requestdispatcher to send anything. I think this might be because of my directory structure?

Comment: Yah, litterally no jstl tags are executed after using sendRedirect(), but the JSP tags are working just fine. If, however, I refresh the page after using sendRedirect, the jstl tags are executed and it prints correctly

Comment: Why are you not using RequestDispatcher ? and to clarify its `response.sendRedirect()` instead of `request.sendRedirect()`

Comment: Errr yah sorry, I meant to say response.sendRedirect. I wanted to use RequestDispatcher but I can't get it to send anything to any page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57815/discussion-between-san-krish-and-user2654735).

Answer (score 0):

Did you use that codes in your jsp;

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
```

And in jsp can you writejust ${mapCarBean}.value.getName() without forEach

Comment: I tried putting your code in and now the session variables aren't coming in at all

Comment: Delete apache tiles and write ${mapCarBean} without forEach

Comment: kk, just tried and nothing prints with page <%@ page session="false"%>, deleting this and retrying prints out {car 1=com.SashaWebsite.car.CarBean@1e20e40b} with ${mapCarBean}. with ${mapCarBean}.value.getName(), it prints out {car 1=com.SashaWebsite.car.CarBean@57e47a0}.value.getName()